# Simple Ceasar Cipher in C

Tags: c, encryption, ascii

I'm working on a simple Ceasar Cipher encryption program in C. I am trying to make it simpler for my son and I to decipher so I put these rules: characters other than letters are unchanged while lowercase and uppercase will remain in their current case (so a Y incremented by 3 would go back to a B). The key and phrase will just be piped using a separate file (my secret!) though a sample of it's contents would be:

```
4 
This line of text will be encrypted.
```

I wanted to buffer it character by character using getchar and putchar so I don't have to bother with an array whose length will always be unknown. How can I check if the character is either an upper or lower case letter and increment it by they given key, while keeping in line with the previous rules. Should putchar be inside the loop to buffer it? Here is my current code

```
#include <stdio.h>  
int main() { 

   int shift; 
   char msgIn, msgOut;

   // space after to keep is from terminating immediately
   scanf("%d ", &shift);
   msgIn = getchar();

   //increment current character and output until newline
   while (msgIn != '\n') {
     //check for upper or lower, else do nothing
     if((msgIn >= 'A') && (msgIn <= 'Z')) {
        msgOut = msgIn + shift; //increment current character, not sure how to handle this better 
        }
     //checking for lower case 
     else if((msgIn >= 'a') && (msgIn <= 'z')) {
        msgOut = msgIn + shift; //increment current character 
        }
     } 

     putchar(msgOut); //output incremented character
   }

   return 0; 
}
```

____ Revised code

```
do {
    msgIn = getchar();

    if((msgIn >= 'A') && (msgIn <= 'Z')) {
        putchar(((msgIn - 'A') + shift) % 26 + 'A'); 
        }
    else if((msgIn >= 'a') && (msgIn <= 'z')) {
        putchar(((msgIn - 'a') + shift) % 26 + 'a'); 
        }
    } 
} while (msgIn != '\n');
```

From your help I am thinking this revised code would do best, haven't tested yet but it looks to handle the loop, input, checking ascii case, handles wrap-around, and output.

Comment: search `[c] Ceasar Cipher`

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning for "not using extra functions" - that just seems like really bad practice and doesn't make anything "simpler".

Comment: This isn't Objective-C code; please don't add that tag again.

Comment: Well the program only has one directive, the use of extra functions wouldn't be needed for a program who's complexity goes so far as to do one simple thing.

Comment: Note that you call `getchar()` only once, outside the loop.  You will want to call it inside the loop, either instead of or in addition to outside, else you will never read past the first character of the message.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I did a search and found nothing pertaining my particular issue of trying to buffer in character by character.

Comment: @John Bollinger If I only called it inside the loop I would have to change it to a do while, which might be better, because I could call it before the If statements each time. if not then I'm calling it at the end to prepare for the next while iteraile

Comment: You're not supposed to take an answer and copy it as part of your original question. You can (and should) simply accept that answer as the correct one, by clicking on the V next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind you want to keep capital letters in uppercase, so what happens when you shift 'Z'?

Take a look at the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator `%` to help.

```
if (msgIn >= 'A' && msgIn <= 'Z') {
    msgOut = 'A' + (msgIn - 'A' + shift) % ('Z' - 'A' + 1);
}
```

This is some code for the capital letter case and will cause the letters to wrap around. 'Z' + 3 becomes 'C' etc.

Comment: I was thinking something similar (though your msgIn and out seem off), more like this: 
    msgOut = ((msgIn - 'A') + shift) % 26 + 'A';

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing by simple you mean easy to understand for your son?  You can 
use a switch statement or a condition, but to keep it simple here is one solution.

```
 shift = 0;     
 if (msgIn>64 && msgIn< 88) shift = 3;
 if (msgIn>87 && msgIn< 90) shift = -23;     

 if (msgIn>64 && msgIn< 120) shift = 3;     
 if (msgIn>119 && msgIn< 123) shift = -23;
```

Comment: You find [Magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) are easier to understand?

Comment: What child doesn't know the ASCII characters - Just kidding.  Yes the chars are nicer.